# cannot import name requests

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I was trying to run the following code but it shows me an error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/python/flask_ass.py",
>   line 1, in 
>       from flask import Flask,requests,json ImportError: cannot import name 'requests'

My code snippet is

```
from flask import Flask, requests, json

# api key=03a84ce64ef242418d262c11a57248de
url = ('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?'
       'country=us&'
       'apiKey=03a84ce64ef242418d262c11a07248de')
params = {'id': 21,
          'name': 'John'}
response = requests.get(url, params=params)

r_dict = response.json()
# print(r_dict)
# print(response.status_code())
print(r_dict['articles'][1]['title'])
# print(response.text)

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def hell():
    return r_dict
```

Comment: `requests` is not part of Flask and can not be imported from there. It's a stand-alone package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`json` and `requests` are not part of `Flask`.

```
from flask import Flask, requests, json
```

should be

```
import json
import requests
from flask import Flask
```

Comment: Yeah I kinda forgot that requests is not a part of a Flask..Solve my error..Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You have a typo,

try the singular:

```
from flask import Flask, request, json
```

BTW, despite the downvotes, I checked and yes,
`from flask import Flask, json` works.

UPDATE: As @DeepSpace mentioned, it's possible that the poster
wanted to import requests & json directly.

```
from flask import Flask
import requests, json
```

Comment: technically correct (`flask` does have an importable `request` module) but OP clearly meant to import the widely used `requests` library (they are doing `requests.get(url, params=params)`)

Comment: @DeepSpace *technically correct* is best correct... , but you're right...

Comment: @DeepSpace, that was a failed humor attempt on "technically correct" but totally wrong, as in: https://tenor.com/view/futurama-you-are-technically-correct-the-best-kind-of-correct-correct-gif-4874011

Comment: sorry, missed the reference ;)